# PHPUnit Mock - Expect 1 of multiple method names to be called

Tags: php, logging, phpunit

Im looking at mocking a logger class within a service and ensuring it attempts to logs erros. It follows `psr/log` interfaces so error logging can be achieved through multiple routes. Calling an `error` method or calling a `log` method with the `LogLevel::error`

Is there a way in PHPUnit mocking to check this.

```
<?php
// Create a mock logger that can be observed
$logger = $this->createMock(LoggerInterface::class);

// This fails is $logger->log(LogLevel::error, 'some message'); is called
$logger
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('error');

// This fail is $logger->error() is called
$logger
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('log')
    ->with(LogLevel::ERROR);
```

Both the methods above do the same thing, log errors so i'm not really bothered which one is used, as long as one is used.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be achieved?

I've seen there is a method called `$this->logicalOr()` but i dont think it's fit for purpose.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Looks similar to the question on github for PHPUnit - https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues/236

Comment: That should do it, thanks alot!

Comment: worked it out, posted the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working. **Asserting that an exception is thrown and logged during a test case**.

*Testing for a scenario similar to this*

```
<?php


class Service
{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;


    public function setLogger(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function doSomething($value)
    {
        try {
            $this->handleDoingSomething($value);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());

            // or optionally

            $this->logger->log(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::ERROR, $e->getMessage());

            throw $e;
        }
    }

    protected function handleDoingSomething($value)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

*Can be achieved by using a test case like this*

```
<?php

class ServiceTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testDoSomething()
    {
        $loggerCalledCount = 0;
        $loggerCallback = function ($methodParameter) use (&$loggerCalledCount) {
            $loggerCalledCount++;

            return true;
        };

        $logger = $this->createMock(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
        $logger->method('error')->with($this->callback($loggerCallback));
        $logger->method('log')->with(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::ERROR, $this->callback($loggerCallback));

        $exceptionCaught = false;
        try {
            $service = new Service();
            $value = 'this value will trigger an exception if used';
            $service->doSomething($value);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $exceptionCaught = true;
        }

        $this->assertTrue($exceptionCaught);
        $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $loggerCalledCount);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps people out.